# Drupal 7: Integration of a module's functionality to another (Email Verify and Guestbook)

Tags: emails, 7

Is it possible to integrate the functionality of the Email Verify module to the Drupal Guestbook module? The latter comprises of a form with email field which I want to be validated using the Email Verify module, whose configuration options only allow checking on the User Registration Form and the User Profile Form. I'd like to expand the functionalities to include the Guestbook, and possibly other forms on the site in the future. Any suggestions on how I can get started would be appreciated.

P.S - I'm using Drupal v7.39